# What types of 'filters' does keras use in filters arguments in keras.layers.Conv2D?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

for this source code:

```
keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=(1, 1), 
                    padding='valid', data_format=None, dilation_rate=(1, 1),
                    activation=None, use_bias=True, 
                    kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', 
                    bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None,
                    bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, 
                    kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None)
```

in filters arguments  we define how many filters we want and the size of the matrix of the filter for example: `.model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))` here we use a number of 64 filters(feature detectors) each of 3*3 size , my question is simpley how will the keras implement these 64 filters ?

Answer (score 1):

They will be simply a trainable weight matrix with size:

```
(kernel_size_x, kernel_size_y, input_filters, output_filters)
```

Which in your example is:

```
(3, 3, filters_of_the_previous_layer, 64)
```

This matrix will be the "filter" argument for the convolutions.

A convolution will be a sliding window with size 3x3 sweeping the pixels of the image, always taking all the input channels and outputting the desired output channels.